# Get heights of loaded elements and add css rule

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of differently sized elements on a page all with the same class of .margin-top-auto

I cannot know the heights of the elements until the page loads.

I need to add {margin-top = the height of each element} to these elements on page load.

Looking for a jQuery/Vanilla snippet that would accomplish this for me.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You haven't provided enough information. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: Respectfully, please tell me what other information I might add. The question seems clear to me.

Comment: I go to every effort to respect this community and I have presented well detailed questions here before. I'm sorry you're not happy with my question but i believe it to be clear and in fact @Spectric has provided me with a working solution for which I am very grateful.

Comment: The fact that someone answered your question doesn't demonstrate that your question meets the standards of this site. You're expected to make an effort to solve the problem yourself. Apparently you haven't. This isn't just my personal position. It's well established in this community.

Comment: I asked you for direction in this regard but you didn’t offer any. I asked the question with all the information that I had available to me. I’m not sure what I might have done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element's [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight):

```js
const height = div.offsetHeight;

div.style.marginTop = height + 'px'

console.log(height)
```

```css
#div{
  background-color:black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

To target multiple elements, you can do:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.margin-top-auto').forEach(e => e.style.marginTop = e.offsetHeight + 'px')
```

```css
.margin-top-auto{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="margin-top-auto"></div>
<div class="margin-top-auto"></div>
<div class="margin-top-auto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your answer you have given a height for your div. I will not have any such height - The height is unknown.

Comment: @BrianyHearne What do you mean? `offsetHeight` will return the height of the element. I applied the height for demonstration purposes.

Comment: So the elements I need to target have the class of .margin-top-auto .  Can you show me how to use your solution with my class?

Comment: @BrianyHearne Sure. I've updated my answer.